# Using Threads in Java class invoked by Worklight Adapter

Tags: java, worklight-adapters, worklight-server, java-threads

We are developing an extension to an existing worklight (6.2) adapter to add some background stuff execution that is not mandatory to provide a response to the client invoking the original adapter.
We thought to implement a new HTTP adapter backed by a java class that starts a thread and invoking this adapter within the original adapter thus performing a kind of asynchronous execution.

Because the worklight internals are not public, we are wondering if this approach is correct or could lead to some problems.

We didn't find any explicit limitation reported in the documentation.

Comment: Hi Idar, thank you for your response. Is your advice something general linked with jee specs, or there are also specific caveats related to worklight?

Answer (score 0):

There are no explicit limitations, but there is an advisory note.

Since you'll be spawning new thread(s) you will need to do this with great care as you will also be the one in charge of the thread(s) life cycle. Not doing so can cause unforeseen server-side behaviors.